# Using Microstrategy Web SDK Java development, I want to retrieve the "Notes" for a report which I am referring through a WebReportInstance object?

Tags: java, microstrategy

I have written a code in Java using Web SDK to open folders present in Microstrategy Desktop and list all the reports. Next thing that I want is to be able to get the data stored under the "Notes" section of each report. I have attached the screenshot of how the Notes section looks like.

Just like we are able to create a WebWorkingSet on a report instance and use **getFilter()** or **getMetrics()** methods to obtain the filters applied or metrics used for that particular report, **is there any method or way in which I can extract the "Notes" written for that report as a string or anything from this report instance?**

I'm using Microstrategy Developer version 10.7 and Web SDK Java development through Eclipse environment.

Any help or hints are always appreciated. Am also OK with any other approach, if suggested. Please help me.
1. [Screenshot1 on how Notes look like in Microstrategy Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZT6xF.png)
2. [Screenshot2 on how Notes appear when opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75nyP.png)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the easiest way to do this is to retrieve the WebReportDefinitionImpl and then call getAnnotations() on it.

See below:

```
          WebReportDefinitionImpl report = (WebReportDefinitionImpl) wos.getObject(
                reportID,
                EnumDSSXMLObjectTypes.DssXmlTypeReportDefinition,
                true);

          String notes = report.getAnnotation();
```

I wrote a blog post on [reverse engineering MicroStrategy Web and Command Manager](http://managingmicrostrategy.com/microstrategy-web-sdk-reverse-engineering-web-and-command-manager/) if you're interested.